# Styling of mx:datagrid in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I want to create a mx:DataGrid component in flex which should like following image:

[image]

I am able to add borders in headers and also able to set header color as white but i am not able to draw the divider line between the rows of the data grid.

here is the code which i am using:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dg" width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{arrDg}" draggableColumns="false"
                 resizableColumns="false" rowCount="{arrDg.length}" selectable="false" headerColors="[white, white]"
                 sortableColumns="false" variableRowHeight="true" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
                 borderColor="0x000000" borderSides="">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF" color="0x000000" dataField="asdf"
                               headerText="asdf"
                               textAlign="center" />
            <mx:DataGridColumn backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF" color="0x000000" dataField="rteyre"
                              headerText="rteyre"
                               headerWordWrap="true" textAlign="center" wordWrap="true"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF" color="0x000000" dataField="xcv"
                              headerText="xcv" textAlign="center"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF" color="0x000000" dataField="hgj"
                              headerText="hgj"
                               headerWordWrap="true" textAlign="center" wordWrap="true"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF" color="0x000000" dataField="yuio"
                              headerText="yuio" textAlign="center"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Please look at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DataGrid.html  add the properties horizontalGridLines="false|true" and    verticalGridLines="false|true"

Comment: thanks man it worked. You can add this as an answer so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DataGrid.html add the properties horizontalGridLines="false|true" and verticalGridLines="false|true" 
Adding it as an answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did yu alter the color of the lines? should be visible by default. try this style for your datagrid:

```
verticalGridLineColor: #000000;
horizontalGridLineColor: #000000;
```